# How to configure chkservd for monitoring redis?

Tags: redis, cpanel

I would like help setting up redis monitoring through chkservd.

Can someone help me, please?

I have tried the following commands but have not been successful.

```
service[redis]=6379,PING,\+PONG,systemctl restart redis.service,redis,redis
```

message: Service check failed to completeredis: [-NOAUT != +PONG

```
service[redis]=6379,redis-cli -a "$password" PING,\+PONG,systemctl restart redis.service,redis,redis
```

message: Service check failed to completeredis: [-ERR w != +PONG]

```
service[redis]=6379,redis-cli -a "$password" -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6379 PING,\+PONG,systemctl restart redis.service,redis,redis
```

message: Service check failed to completeredis: [-ERR w != +PONG]

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
service[redis]=x,redis-cli ping,\+PONG,systemctl restart redis
```